# jQuery getJSON not working,getting Unresponsive Script error

Tags: jquery, json

I am trying to load some JSON data into to a table using the getJSON method but Im getting an Unresponsive Script error in Firefox and in Chrome it crashes.The JSON objet has got over 50,000 items and I'm sure this is causing the script to fail.I was planning to inject the JSON data into a table and use the jquery dataTables plugin for paging,sorting and filtering.

Could some one please suggest a better way of doing what Im trying to do?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $.getJSON("items.php",function(result){
    $.each(result, function(i, field){

       var html = '<tr><td>' + field['id'] + '</td>';
       html+='<td>'+ field['name'] + '</td>';
       html+='<td>'+ field['price'] + '</td></tr>';

       $('#itemsTable').append(html);


    });
  });
});
```

I have changed my code to this now but now I get the error json.aaData is UNDEFINED ..js/jquery.dataTables.min.js

```
$('#tbData').dataTable( {
                    "bProcessing": true,
                    "bServerSide": true,
                    "sAjaxSource": 'items.php'
                } );
```

Comment: maybe try to append only once (outside of the loop)

Comment: maybe problem is the weight of the response body but... are you sure your items.php script returns a Content-Type: application/json Header?

Comment: are you sure your `items.php` works fine? do you receive proper JSON when you run `items.php` in browser window?

Comment: I dont know much about the php file but it has got echo json_encode($dataarrary); in the end, will this not be enough to return a JSON ?And yes I can view the JSON when I run the file in the browser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is absolutely no need to parse your own table, then trigger datatables on it. Pass your data directly to datatables plugin and let it handle it using data source options from API

Your append for every row is grossly inefficient. datatables will keep most of your data in an object and only generate enough html for the view required

Comment: thanks for your answer im tryying to do like u suggested i have changed my code to like you said but now I get the error json.aaData is UNDEFINED../js/jquery.dataTables.min.js

Comment: can't tell much from that, if using php there is a good CRUD example in API. Also json response examples

Answer (score 0):

one option is get data using paging 100 , after 100 till all data.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $.getJSON("items.php?start=0&end=100",function(result){
    $.each(result, function(i, field){

       var html = '<tr><td>' + field['id'] + '</td>';
       html+='<td>'+ field['name'] + '</td>';
       html+='<td>'+ field['price'] + '</td></tr>';

       $('#itemsTable').append(html);


    });
  });


$.getJSON("items.php?start=100&end=200",function(result){
    $.each(result, function(i, field){

       var html = '<tr><td>' + field['id'] + '</td>';
       html+='<td>'+ field['name'] + '</td>';
       html+='<td>'+ field['price'] + '</td></tr>';

       $('#itemsTable').append(html);


    });

});
```

like this till all..

or make forach that incremnet start and end.

here u can aapend one by one or concat string.